# R: Create a histogram showing the distribution of the trade balance per continent

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

How can I show this distribution?
R is very new for me!!
My data looks like this:

It's: Tradepartner, Year, Neighboured Country, Tradebalance, Continent.
There would as well be Imports but I think this is not important for this exercise?!

```
   TradepP.  Year   Exp.    Neighb.Coun Tradebalance Continent
1  usa       2008   23250.6      0         -2449.423   America
2  sgp       2008   4266.50      0          3295.2080     Asia
3  ita       2008   19883.80     1         -4956.684    Europe
4  ind       2008  2235.366      0        1287.24644     Asien
5  hkg       2008  7854.904      0        4087.74450     Asien
6  gbr       2008 19321.775      0        1914.01707    Europa
7  fra       2008 21245.290      1         702.86881    Europa
8  deu       2008 49782.716      1      -14688.09358    Europa
9  chn       2008  9025.037      0        2499.00703     Asien
10  aut      2008  8398.346      1         228.11745    Europa
11  ita      2009 16574.162      1       -5119.07550    Europa
12  ind      2009 10459.321      0        9374.54024     Asien
13  hkg      2009  6763.256      0        2628.96126     Asien
14  gbr      2009 19771.318      0        9851.84638    Europa
15  fra      2009 18571.506      1        1959.00240    Europa
16  deu      2009 42781.572      1      -11412.06434    Europa
17  usa      2009 20802.857      0         153.48332   Amerika
18  sgp      2009  3455.538      0        2136.15896     Asien
19  chn      2009  7913.221      0        2530.38011     Asien
20  aut      2009  8548.104      1        1107.86531    Europa
```

I tried to order it by continent but I failed...^^

The csv data is: `Exporte_CH_total_OLAT`

```
Exporte_CH_total_OLAT %>% 
  group_by(Continent) %>%
  select(Continent,Year,Tradebalance) %>%
  arrange(Continent)

ggplot(Exporte_CH_total_OLAT,aes(x=Year, y=)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black",fill="lightblue", binwidth = 0.1)
```

This totaly didn't worked out!
Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You do not put any kind of data, and `geom_histogram() ` does not need `x` and `y`. However, use `dput(head(Exporte_CH_total_OLAT,20))`and post the output editing the question, you'll share your first 20 rows of  your data and you'll increase the chance to get an answer. If you cannot share your data, add some fake data to make your code and issues reproducible. In case, which is the variable you want to put in an histogram?

Comment: You could try specifying your something like this: `aes(x = Year, y = Tradebalance, color = Continent) + geom_histogram(binwidth = .01)`. I can't test it given the lack of data, but hopefully that will get you one stepp closer. You are essentially specifying a third dimension for your variable with `color`.

Comment: Too late to edit my previous commnet. @s_t is corret. Maybe this instead:  `aes(Tradebalance, fill = Continent) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)`. Make sure your data is grouped by year.

Comment: If it try these codes:
 `aes(Tradebalance, fill = Continent) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)`
it says that R wouldn't find Continent

Comment: If it try:
`dput(head(Exporte_CH_total_OLAT,20)`
then nothing happens, I dont get a histogram in the plots

Comment: @mara- you forget a `)` in the end. Also, it's not going to give you a histogram, but something like `structure(...` and you have to paste it in the question (editing it) to share some data. From that, we can start to create an histogram (remember to say which column you want to plot).

Comment: @mara- with your data now is easier: could you specify better what you want to see? A simple histogram for Tradebalance? Divided by something? If an histogram, each "brick" of the bars, what should it be? Does it make sense to you this `library(tidyverse);
Exporte_CH_total_OLAT %>%
  ggplot(aes(Tradebalance)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(vars(Year))`?